# How to correctly type a condtional object assign function in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following function that should assign all defined members of sourceObject to an existing destination member in destObject. Igonore all properties which are not shared between the objects. Also allows to omit fields

I tried the following:

```js
    export function updateObjectProps<TS extends {[key: string]: unknown}, TD extends Partial<TS>>(
      destinationObject: TD,
      sourceObject: TS,
      omittedFields: (keyof TS | 'id')[] = ['id'],
    ) {
    for (const key in sourceObject) {
        if(sourceObject.hasOwnProperty(key) && key in destinationObject) {
            if (!omittedFields.includes(key)) {
                destinationObject[key] = sourceObject[key] // type not correct here
            }
        }
      }
      return destinationObject
    }
    
    const obj1 = {a: 1, b: 2}
    const obj2 = {a: 2, d: 3}
    
    updateObjectProps(obj1, obj2)
```

Is there a way to make such a function typesafe with?

Answer (score 0):

Yea there is, but considering the `omittedFields` makes it a little hacky. Here's the working [sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gtgS2MCATAYgiAbVBnAHgGUB7AVwCcBjCGAIwCsIrgA+KAXigAoBrCECQBmUUpRr0mLKAB8oAcgSp5ASgDaAXQCwAKFCQoASQB2qBDTycoeYBQTGA5rKjGycOhArO8IdyWy6+tAA4hDGnuaSzMBWAN5q-CBQ9kam5hB4GgBcUGTGvMYkAO7GAL66FToQAB5gJBQxQnksCCTGuWCoAIYoUSwAChQkYIRi1LSM0VA1KKaWoeF2VH3AADRQACIZwPY9rcYr09Wz+FDxicnticKi5OMrGgD8OXkFxWXrAOqs3LpQ-1BUNtdjs2isclsbCD9itVn8AXg7hJJiwcmNkVI1vD-gB6HEAAWAeAAtAgHIUKBBsVASIhkGhMDh8DlPlAAGSwOkoDBYXCjJETTHsLhqABESlFGjhOhUOXOAkuUAAotUqNgyECCNcROjBdEvkcTpYusYQJooI8oJ81K53J4NFAcuEAG6edhybWbYHGPZglHAbJQC4zMKnT26w6WiP+hICB05YPHUOWT2QnY+0EHf0Wr1QjMwmOJeMuCCuijlHS6WLUoT1HhUNo2IMKlKI8R6lgqM7UgHJITcNv3f0AOgAFl08DASoNhp5QHwBF22RyLikgXnfVnMV3qzpe-uAQgRNwAIS0pDcxl84f2NUajILpITqAmkAqHc9g-7vGEklkilUnuX7Aeu6abissYgA6XCDhi0SQQ6eJQEELgkDEDYUJS0ijp4gHAb2FbAYRALEf8lLAJQ7SgdCfqYi+xqmroFa6A2xhNiQjAAIxxF0OScesdA5AATBWrHsYwQk8cJ6yoDkADMzE6GJMSUpYXBkJ0PQdsAM4jNwHEMPxNISSolSVEAA).

I took the liberty to change some of your variable names.

```
type OmittedFields<SourceObject> = (keyof SourceObject | 'id')[]
type Indices = string | number | symbol
type GenericObject = {[key in Indices]: unknown}


export function updateObjectProps<SourceObject extends GenericObject, DestinationObject extends {[key in keyof SourceObject]?: unknown}, W>(
    destinationObject: DestinationObject,
    sourceObject: SourceObject,
    //@ts-ignore
    omittedFields: W & OmittedFields<SourceObject> = ["id"],
): {[key in Exclude<keyof SourceObject, W extends any[] ? W[number] : never> | keyof DestinationObject]: key extends keyof SourceObject ? SourceObject[key] : key extends keyof DestinationObject ? DestinationObject[key] : never}
{
    ...
}

const obj1 = {a: 1, b: 2}
const obj2 = {a: 2, d: 3}

const res = updateObjectProps(obj1, obj2)
```

---

## Explanation

You can iterate over both the indices of `SourceObject` and `DestinationObject` and set the values to whatever you like. This can be done using mapped types: `{key in keyof MyOb}: MyOb[key]`

```
type Mapped = {[key in keyof SourceObject | keyof DestinationObject]: SourceOrDest<key>}
```

Then you can set the values to ether `SourceObject` value type (if available) or default to `DestinationObject` value type. This can be done using conditional types: `A extends B ? true : false`

```
type SourceOrDest<key> = key extends keyof SourceObject ? SourceObject[key] : key extends keyof DestinationObject ? DestinationObject[key] : never 

// We will never get to `never`. It must be keyof Source or Destination.
```

To omit `omittedFileds` from `SourceObject` we can `Exclude` some indices from the union we take to iterate (in our mapped type). This works like this: `type Ex = Exclude<"A" | "B" | "C", "C">`. Here `Ex` would be `"A" | "B"`

Now we merely have to get to the given type of `omittedFields`. This is where it gets a little hacky, because writing `W` extends `OmittedFields<SourceObject>` will not work, as `W` will default to `OmittedFields<SourceObject>` if it is omitted by the function caller. Thus, we have to declare `omittedFields` as having the type of `OmittedFields<SourceObject>` as you were writing, but then also infer the actual given value as a plan Generic (`W`) without any type specifications. This will result in `W` being `unknown` when no argument is provided, which we can check by using a conditional type again.

```
type C = W extends any[] ? : W[number] : never
```

When `W` is given, it must extend any[] thus we can convert the given values of the tuple (array) to a union like so: `W[number]`. If it is not given as Argument, thus `unknown` we just default to `never` as `"A" | "B" | never === "A" | "B"` (it gets discarded by unions).

Here is an explanation for the tuple > Union conversion

```
type tuple = ["a" | "b"]
type union = tuple[number] // "A" | "B"
```

If you got any questions, just hit me up!